# Is it safe to store user-uploaded ID scans in S3 (with server encryption)?

Tags: encryption, web-application, amazon-s3

Currently my web app stores user-uploaded ID scans in S3. I am concerned about an eventual data leak.

The S3 bucket is encrypted with server-side encryption (AES-256) but I figure the next obvious risk is an attacker gaining access to the AWS account itself. I have secured the root account with 2FA but there are several user accounts which have full access to S3 still (such as a Travis CI account).

The solution I am thinking of is periodically moving the ID scans to a different source with client-side encryption (where only I know the private key). That way if a leak happens, there will be only a small amount of data leaked.

Is this a common practice or are there better solutions in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common way to store these more sensitive documents is to encrypt them with KMS.

Unlike the `AES-256` encryption (which AWS themselves claim to be slightly legacy), KMS encryption requires a separate permission to decrypt and encrypt the files.

Create a Customer Managed Customer-Master-Key(CMK) in KMS, and upload the files encrypting them with CMK in question (using the `kms:Encrypt` permission).

Then whatever needs to decrypt the files (e.g. a Lambda function etc), needs to have the `kms:Decrypt` permission on the CMK in question.

Travis can have access to the bucket, but can never access the content of the files, as it should never be granted the `kms:Decrypt` on the key.

CMKs cost a tiny amount of money, but generally worth-it if you're getting folks to upload IDs into your app.